# Why did African Americans and Native Americans vote too oppositely on the Affirmative Action poll?

Tags: united-states, democracy, racism, affirmative-action

I found a tabular analysis on Wikipedia about affirmative action. It shows: "*Supporters and opponents of affirmative action in California 2020*".

| Popular Group | For Affirmative Action | Against Affirmative Action | Neutral |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Whites | 35 % | 53 % | 12 % |
| **African Americans** | **58 %** | **33 %** | 10 % |
| Asians | 39 % | 50 % | 11 % |
| Latinos | 40 % | 42 % | 17 % |
| **Native Americans** | **22 %** | **72 %** | 4 % |

**Sources:** 1. https://escholarship.org/uc/item/5nf4r5hz, 2. https://www.cbsnews.com/sanfrancisco/news/prop-16-repeal-affirmative-action-ban-trailing-uc-berkeley-igs-poll/

What I noticed is that only African Americans are majority in favour of Affirmative Action. But what surprised me even more was that the group of Native Americans had the lowest support for affirmative action. Yet, from my European-German point of view, these are exactly the groups that have been discriminated against most often and for the longest time in the USA? Why then this ambivalence?

As already mentioned, I am European and have never been to the US. But I have heard some things at school, but also through the media and stories from acquaintances.

Comment: Is that table an accurate representation of the questions asked? If the questions were about support for a particular proposition—something as complicated as support for repealing a ban, say—it does not necessarily make sense to equate those to support for or opposition to affirmative action in general.

Comment: @Obie2.0 That is a good and legitimate question. But unfortunately I don't know.

Comment: Any time you are looking at surveys of Native Americans, issue #1 is survey sample size, representativeness of the sample, and the definition of Native American used.

Comment: @ohwilleke Thank you for the comment. I understand the size of the sample. But what do you mean by the definition of the term "Native American". Are there different definitions of "Native American" in the US?

Comment: @MaikLowrey Yes. A strict definition, for example, might limit "Native Americans" to people who are formally affiliated with a tribe. But in the census and for many purposes relying on self-identification, lots of people who identify as Native American have a reputed family history of having some small amount of Native American ancestry and no living cultural connection to any Native American community (e.g. Elizabeth Warren), especially in the South. So in a loose definition, many "Native Americans" are predominantly, by ancestry and in their daily cultural practices, rural whites.

Comment: @ohwilleke Ok. Thanks for the answer. I was not aware of that. But it is very interesting. I suppose that this group could still experience racism because of their appearance or their name. Or is there a difference between Native Americans and African Americans on this point?

Comment: @MaikLowrey A large share of people who identify as Native Americans in the U.S. even including many with strong tribal affiliations (probably well over 50%) can pass for white and do not have distinctively Native American names. In contrast, probably fewer than 5% of African Americans can pass for white in appearance, and a large share of African Americans have distinctive names that reflect their ethnicity. Also, many people in the U.S. with significant indigenous Mesoamerican and S. American ancestry, who have an indigenous phenotype/appearance, identify as Hispanic.

Comment: See generally https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States#Racial_identity

Comment: @ohwilleke after looking at the pictures of the wikipedia linka, i have to agree with you. thanks to you!

Comment: @MaikLowrey There are a lot of differences between historical treatment of people of African descent and people of Native American descent.

Comment: could easily be attributed to low sampling; it's the smallest group in population and only group shown with all even numbers, which suggests scaling to me.

Comment: I suspect that most Americans view AA as primarily benefiting blacks. So even though Latinos and Native Americans might be able to take advantage of it, they don't realize it and answer negatively.

Comment: According to your first link, the question was not about affirmative action as such, but repealing [Proposition 209 (1996)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1996_California_Proposition_209). Subjects were randomly chosen and invited by email to take a survey on a web site. It's unclear what fraction of invitees participated. There were 105 "unweighted" / 71 "weighted" Native American respondents (the latter being likely voters?). It's unclear if race was taken from voter registration data or was self-reported (people making up answers tend to choose unusual races, professions, etc.).